# Google Dataflow CombineFn add_input failure

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Using python SDK of Google Dataflow
I have overridden CombineFn to do multi-field aggregation instead of one field at a time. The interface for add_input as per the documentation is intermediate aggregate and input values after grouping. For example:
Assuming 
    id1, 100
    id1, 200
    id1, 300
    id2, 100
    id2, 300
    id2, 400

My second call to add_input function should receive (100,) and (200,) as current aggregate and new value to be added to the accumulator. This functionality is working perfectly in the local runner scenario.

When I move to google dataflow engine, I see one set of logs with above condition where it completes the aggregates for id1 and id2. Then out of nowhere I see another call for add_input with intermediate_value being assinged with input value (200,) and input_value being assigned with aggregated value in the previous calculation.

I am unable to understand the reason for second set of calls of add_input when the first pass finished all the calculations. Any insight will help?

To summarize:

On further analysis, It looks like add_input is being called with two sets of intermediate aggregates for the same key. As per the interface it should be intermediate aggregate + input value in this pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On further analysis, It looks like add_input is being called with two sets of intermediate aggregates for the same key. As per the interface it should be intermediate aggregate + input value in this pass.

It sounds like you are calling `add_input` from your `merge_accumulators` function.
It would help to see your `CombineFn` code.

More importantly is ultimate output of your `CombineFn` step correct?

Here's a `CombineFn` from one of my pipelines in case it helps to look at another example.

```
class MergeDictCombineFn(beam.core.CombineFn):
    """
    CombineFn function that merges all of the dictionaries from the previous step

    {'a': 1}, {'a': 2, 'b':1}, {'c': 1} -> {'a': 3, 'b':1, 'c': 1}
    """

    def _sum_up(self, elements, accumulator=None):
        accumulator = accumulator or self.create_accumulator()
        for obj in elements:
            for k, v in obj.iteritems():
                if k not in accumulator:
                    accumulator[k] = 0
                accumulator[k] += v
        return accumulator

    def create_accumulator(self):
        return {}

    def add_input(self, accumulator, element, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._sum_up(elements=[element], accumulator=accumulator)

    def add_inputs(self, accumulator, elements, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._sum_up(elements=elements, accumulator=accumulator)

    def merge_accumulators(self, accumulators, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._sum_up(elements=accumulators)

    def extract_output(self, accumulator, *args, **kwargs):
        return accumulator
```

Comment: Yes Alex, I was indeed calling the add_input from merge input to reuse computational logic. I had to parse the input value to suit the format required for add_input function. Thank you for your response.